# Public std::reference_wrapper unwrapper

Tags: c++, c++17

The standard namespace has `std::_Unrefwrap_t` to unwrap a `std::reference_wrapper`. Noting the unique naming, I assume that this is not something actually in the standard and is merely in my implementation. Is there a public and actually supported unwrapper for `std::reference_wrapper`?

Answer (score 1):

There is a [std::unwrap_reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/unwrap_reference) starting with the C++20. There is no `std::_Unrefwrap_t` in the standard-library.

The initial underscore and capital letter in the `_Unrefwrap_t` name suggests it is an implementation detail.

Comment: @nowi Yes. It's new in C++20 - because there was no such thing in C++17.

Comment: This site is useful to the entire community. You might not be able to use c++20 now, but this answer is and will be helpful. Also on the linked page you have a possible simple implemention that you can use.

Comment: The good news is that it's really easy to write your own `unwrap_reference` for use before C++20.